# About an example

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I want to find a function $f$ such that

- $|f(x)|\leq k |x|^{\alpha} $ where $k>0$ and $\alpha\in[0,1)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$
- $f'(0)=0$

Please thank you.

Comment: Apart from the inevitable $f\equiv 0$, take a look at $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{x^{\frac32}}{1+x^2} s^{\frac12}$ how to choose $k$ please

Comment: You may choose $k=1$.

Comment: but $\frac{x^{\frac32}}{1+x^2}$ is not les or equal 1 for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @mqx please why k=1

Comment: You may choose $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$, $k=1$, and your required properties are satisfied.

Comment: I stady the function $g(x)=\frac{x^{2-\sigma}}{1+x^2}$, $g'(x)= \frac{x^{1-\sigma}(2-\sigma(1-x^2))}{(1+x^2)^2}$ but i don't know how to continu please help me

Comment: I am sorry, why do you study $g$?

Comment: to see that it is right that $k=1$ and $\sigma\in [0,1)$ ($\sigma$ is $\alpha$ )